# how to deploy ssl certification with Odoo12 ubuntu server?

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, odoo

I installed ubuntu server and odoo12 
and I installed SSL certification on the main domain https://alialhinai.com/ .. but the SSL doesn't work with odoo http://alialhinai.com:8069

can anyone assist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your setup. Are you using Odoo on your own server or hosted on odoo.com? The document refers only to cases where you have your domain hosted in Odoo Online at odoo.com

Comment: @SachinYadav It's hosted on my own server and my own domain.

Comment: Probabilly your nginx has an incorrect configuration.
See this article to help yourself: https://medium.com/@othmane.ghandi/running-odoo-in-https-using-nginx-certbot-90ef2f3e5ccb

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have custom domain with SSL cert for it in pure self-service Odoo Online.

The documentation only refers to using external CDN with SSL certs. Some Odoo.com forum posts say that you can ask for this from Odoo support by email. You can try that.

Another option is to have separate reverse proxy for your domain with ssl cert and route traffic to yourdomain.odoo.com from there.